# Convert DataFrame into dict

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dictionary

[I use pandas to read df.csv, so I have a Dataframe Like this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kErXL.png)

[I want to convert it to dict like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlogA.png)

Comment: Please, make sure the images are text, or at least embedded

Comment: See [pd.to_dict()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

try :

```
df.to_dict(orient='list')
```